# Cross site scripting invoked via document.write()

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, jhipster, jscript

Can anyone tell how to allow the cross site scripting in the jhipster so that the warning can be resolved?

> A Parser-blocking cross site (i.e. different jsapi:22 eTLD+1) script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=elements&v=1&packages=transliteration,
>   is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be
>   confirmed in a subsequent console message. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details

as well as multiple occurences of the same message referencing different Google scripts.

Comment: [Don't post screenshots.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1553851)

Answer (score 2):

The warning you're receiving is due to you including the [Google Transliterate API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) in a manner which may result in poor user experience on devices with slow network connections.

Somewhere in the scripts for your site, you'll have a line which looks something like this:

```
document.write('<script src="https://www.google.com/uds/?file=elements&v=1&packages=transliteration"></script>');
```

There may be multiple scripts in one `document.write` or they may be split across several calls. This may not be the only thing in the call to `document.write`.

To remove this warning, you'll need to move all of your `<script>` tags outside of calls to `document.write`.

See [this post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write) for more details.